# I'm trying to compile my SCSS code into CSS but the variables are not found

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to set a page with a package.json file I just build to compile my Sass into CSS but when compiling it says my variables are not found. Probably it's something very stupid but I can't see why not.

This is my json file

```
    "watch:sass": "node-sass --watch sass/main.scss css/style.css ",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
  },`
```

This is my main.scss

```
@import "nav";
@import "base";
```

And this is my _base.scss

```
$text-dark: #2c2c2c;
$background-extra-dark: #6B7883;
``
```

Comment: Add a bit of style.scss with relevant to the point

Answer (score 0):

Oh, nevermind. 
I know why.

Always import the variables first!

```
@import "base";
@import "nav";
```